# trainCascadeObjectDetector How does it work?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

Can someone direct me to a document or some kind of source about the "magic" behind trainCascadeObjectDetector? I was looking around for quite a bit but couldn't find anything. Thank you for your time.

Comment: MATLAB help files often cite references for their algorithms. Look there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [answer on MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/197856-how-does-traincascadeobjectdetector-work):

Hello Dai,

Do you need to explain how the face detector itself works, or how the training of the face detector works?

vision.CascadeObjectDetector implements the [deletection algorithm by Viola and Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%25E2%2580%2593Jones_object_detection_framework). It is a "sliding-window" approach, which slides a window across an image, and tries to determine whether or not there is a face in each location using a cascade of boosted classifiers. The original algorithm uses Haar-like features. vision.CacadeObjectDetector also gives you the option to use LBP or HOG features.

The [Algorithms section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector-class.html#zmw57dd0e60485) of the vision.CascadeObjectDetector documentation gives a good high-level overview of what it is doing.

As far as the training process, there is a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) in the documentation explaining some of the details.